# Cintiq Pro 13 doesn't display on Windows 10 System

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, bios, thunderbolt

This [recently launched Cintiq](http://www.wacom.com/products/pen-displays/wacom-cintiq-pro-13) supposed to work with a single USB-C connection.

I have a Motherboard [Asus z270-AR](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/PRIME-Z270-AR/) with USB-C port, but when I connect it, the cintiq works fine as a tablet, but it doesn't display anything.

Could it be misconfiguration on BIOS/ Thunderbolt?

What I also tried:
The product comes with a adaptor which converts usb-C to Standard USB + Mini displayport. I don't have Mini displayport, I tested with multiples third party adaptors (to Displayport, to DVI, to HDMI). Any of them worked.

I tried on other 3 computers with Win 10 with Standard USB + Minidisplay port + 3rd party adapters. Any of them worked.

I tried on a Mac with Standard USB + Minidisplay port. It worked.

---

PC Specs:
Asus z270-AR

- List item
- Windows 10
- Standard Monitor Display on Nvidia GTX660

Comment: I wonder if not all USB C connections do video over USB C

Comment: Yes, it is exactly this, @JourneymanGeek! Thank you!

Comment: Hah! Thought so, and its nice to have confirmation. Anything thunderbolt 3 should do said alternate mode. Not sure about regular USB C ports though.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes! I suppose Thunderbolt 3 should work. In the answer I posted, I linked and article talking about USB-C alternate protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make it work by getting the best Mini displayport to Displayport cable adaptor with 4x x 2k resolution, but after making sure my graphic card has DisplayPort version 1.2.

Before I had tried a lower quality cable with no success.

I discovered Cintiq Pro requires USB-C with Alternate DisplayPort Protocol, as said in this [Review on Youtube (min 1:40)](https://youtu.be/7HFL3zYswyc?t=1m38s).

More information about [USB-C Alternate protocols](http://blog.fosketts.net/2016/10/29/total-nightmare-usb-c-thunderbolt-3/).

Then I found a link from the [Wacom itlsef saying about HDMI compatibility](https://wacom.com/en-br/support/faqs/cintiq%20pro%2013%20-%2016/does%20the%20new%20wacom%20cintiq%20pro%20and%20wacom%20mobilestudio%20pro%20support%20hdmi%20connection%20to%20a%20computer): it may work in specific situations, but it has a lot of issues (not recommended).